# How to user string interpolation in Flutter to call a function

Tags: string, flutter, dart, string-interpolation

I have 2 methods, `tappedNext()` and `tappedPrevious()`, i need to call this function by passing a string variable, e.g `onTap: tapped + part + ()`, is it possible to make a string interpolation for this like `tapped${part}()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I certainly do not recommend you to do that. Instead, use a simple if statement.
But since you asked if it is possible..

Short answer, no (with a function only). Unless you're talking about methods, in that case we could use some mirrors.

You'll need to import the mirror package, it doesn't work on dartpad, so test it locally:

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class MyClass {
  tappedNext() {
    print('Next Function');
  }

  tappedPrevious() {
    print('Previous Function');
  }
}
```

Now you must create an object from the class, create a mirror of it, and then make use of a `Symbol` to call the method in a reflectly way.

```dart
void main() {
  final clazz = MyClass();
  final mirror = reflect(clazz);

  final function = 'Next';

  Symbol s = Symbol('tapped$function');
  mirror.invoke(s, []).reflectee;
}
```

That's it, the console will print:

> Next Function

Comment: Thank you very, much, i used if... else definitely, that was a stupid idea.